# How can I extract metrics?

Tags: export, jira, reporting, metrics

The stock reports provided by Atlassian do not cover what I would like to investigate

Without buying 3rd party controls, how can I extract data from Jira to play around with and create my own reports and analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on JIRA rest api: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use this: https://bitbucket.org/kaszaq/howfastyouaregoing/ - library which greatly simplifies creation of any metrics based on data from Jira which is cached locally so it does not need to connect and pull issues from Jira each time.